# VB.NET HIWORD from Int32

Tags: vb.net, casting, vb6

I have a low level mouse hook:

```
Public Structure MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
    Public pt As Point
    Public mouseData As Int32
    Public flags As Int32
    Public time As Int32
    Public dwExtraInfo As IntPtr
End Structure
```

I would like to get the high word from "mouseData" like this:

```
Dim iWheelDelta As Integer = HIWORD(myhookstruct.mouseData)
```

So far I did this in VB6, and there I used a

```
Public Function HIWORD(LongIn As Long) As Integer
    CopyMemory HIWORD, ByVal VarPtr(LongIn) + 2, 2
End Function
```

However, I guess and hope that there is safe method in VB.NET.

Can somebody help?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use [this](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/ndp/fx/src/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/NativeMethods.cs#e1ab28ba69954959#references)

Comment: This is C#, not VB.NET.

Comment: Why on earth you tagged c# then? Nevermind you can convert it [here](http://converter.telerik.com/)

Comment: Sorry, had a C# example in my posting and then took it out again, however I forgot to remove the tag. I already tried your approach before my post, but I got a weird result telling me that Cast to the same type is not valid.